# Custom field type not accessible in usermodel

Tags: fieldtypes, custom-fieldtype

I have altered the Craft usermodel using some standard field types (like an entry field type) and an customfieldtype (extended from the EntriesFieldType). The only thing I have altered in the child fieldtype is some validation rules and the prepValue method. I dont get any errors saving this new field type but when I try to access it eg:

```
    $lCurrentUser = craft()->userSession->getUser();
    $lCompanyIdUser1 = $lCurrentUser->companiesDropdown[0]->id;
    $lCompanyIdUser2 = $lCurrentUser->companyUser[0]->id;
```

companiesDropdown is a standard "Craft" Entries fieldtype 
companyUser is the custom fieldType

the error is get is : 
Undefined property: Craft\UserModel::$companyUser (i've tripple checked the handle name)

Please advise,

Thanks in advance.

(ps I'm running Craft 2.2)

Comment: Are you sure you've added that exact field to your user profile field layout?

Comment: Yes, And I can use it. Meaning I can drag in an entry and it saves successfully. And I also see it in a var_dump on the user object

Comment: I'm not really sure why it wouldn't be working. Can you send a DB backup and your plugin to support@buildwithcraft.com? I can look into it from there.

Comment: May be its because I try to do the above in the prepValue method. I think ->companyUser is not known at that time yet. If I execute the same in the validate method upon saving I can access this fieldType. Does that make sense?